# Is it not feasible to make PHP run on .js pages?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm curious about passing PHP output to Javascript. Two things specifically:

- I'm assuming this can be done safely using script tags on a .php page. Is there any reason not to?
- Can you make PHP run on .js pages? What configuration changes would be required? And again, would there be a reason not to?

Comment: Why is the type of data you want to pass to Javascript? Is is dynamic (something that will be updated regularly) or static content?

Comment: My particular issue is development server vs. production server. I was thinking of ways to have just one page that would need to stay unique between them, and have both PHP and Javascript pick up the variables (for things like host URLs etc). I wanted to keep the question more broad though since I can think of other uses for this. But to answer your question, no, in my case the data wouldn't be changing often.

Comment: I don't see the link between your question and the dev/prod environments. Maybe adding in the question some example of the variables you want to use may help us to see what you want to do.

Comment: If I need to declare, let's say, a string for the host URL, or a path, those differ between dev and production environments. Being able to output PHP to Javascript, I could have one PHP file where I declare those settings, and both JS and PHP can pick up those same variables. That way I can always upload and replace every other file from dev to prod and everything will still work. And if I need to change a setting, like a path or hostname, I would only need to do it in one place.

Comment: I see, thanks for the examples. But I think it's another problem and off-topic from this question. I suggest you to post a new question. Anyway, your idea of configuration file specifics for each environment is good (Symfony2 uses it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming this can be done safely using script tags on a .php page. Is there any reason not to?

Yes.  No reason not to.

> Can you make PHP run on .js pages? What configuration changes would be required? And again, would there be a reason not to?

Yes, you would have to configure your webserver to use the PHP module for the .js suffix.  On nginx you might add a location line for files ending in .js:-

```
location ~ \.js$
{
}
```

On Apache you'd do something like:-

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .js
```

One reason you might not want to do this, is that any static JS files would go through the PHP module and that would cause additional overhead.  Another option would be to reference the PHP file in the HTML script tags eg:-

```
<script src="myfile.php"></script>
```

and then make sure your PHP returns its output with the correct content-type eg:-

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right on both counts.

- You can output dynamic content (PHP) in a `<script>` tag on a `.php` page
- You can output dynamic content (PHP) in an all-javascript file, though the extension would still be `.php`

## Example 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myobject = {
    data: '<?php echo $myPHPvariable; ?>';
};
// or better yet:
var myBetterObject = <?php echo json_encode($myPhpObject); ?>;

function foo () { ... }
</script>
```

## Example 2

*Not recommended*

```
<?php
// This is an all-javascript file but the extension ends with .php

header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
?>

var myobject = {
    data: '<?php echo $myPHPvariable; ?>';
};
function foo () { ... }
```

Then you include that file in your HTML document with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom_javascript.php"></script>
```

It should definitely end with `.php`, and thankfully the web browser knows it is JavaScript by the `type="text/javascript"` part and because your PHP script outputs the right `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is simpler : declare some JS variables in the output HTML, they can be constant or generated by the PHP code:

```html
<script>
var my_variable = '<?php echo($my_variable); ?>';
</script>
```

Then you can use this variable in your Javascript code.

The `.js` files should be static to allow the browser to cache them, so they won't be loaded every time the user loads a page. By generating `.js` files on the fly with PHP, you may have problems with browsers using cached `.js` instead of the expected generated file. For example, if your variable contains dynamic content as the last news from your website, a datetime, etc.

So, yes you can do it, but you'll have to prevent the browser to cache the file, increasing the bandwidth usage or expect unexpected behaviours with browsers loading cached `.js` files. There's no benefit in using this way.

Comment: You won't have problems if you tell the browser not to cache them

Comment: I agree, but it's a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, ideally you would only do this for when variable where you declare all the data you need to get dynamically from the server and tell browsers to cache all your other .js for a year or so, then just invalidate them with query strings when you modify them.